# React Native: libRCTFBSDKCore.a and libRCTFBSDK.a conflict

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a project in react-native that integrate both RCTFBSDK and also RCTFBSDKCore in the project. When i compile I have of course the two .a with conflict (duplicate objects).

If I remove -Objc from Other Linker flags of course it compiles but the app crash as the -Objc is required.

I am quite in a dead loop, how this can be fixed?